# How can I create a new table with 2 columns from old table with many columns, where column names changes for every run

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

```
public void createTables() throws SQLException
{
    String qs1=ss[0][0];
    String qs2=ss[0][1];
    Statement stmt;
    String q1="CREATE TABLE table1 AS (SELECT PID,:qs1,:qs2 FROM patient)";
    System.out.println(" I am Here.....");
    String q2="CREATE TABLE table2 AS (SELECT pid,symptom,dateofdiagnosis FROM patient)";
    String q3="CREATE TABLE table3 AS (SELECT pid,physician,diagnosismethod FROM patient)";
    stmt =conn.createStatement();
    System.out.println(" I am Here.....");
    //pst1.setString(1,ss[0][0]);
    //pst1.setString(2,ss[0][1]);
    System.out.println(" I am Here....."+ss[0][0]);
    pst2=conn.prepareStatement(q2);
    pst3=conn.prepareStatement(q3);
    boolean execute = stmt.execute(q1);
    pst2.execute();
    pst3.execute();
}
```

I wanted to create a table from previous table where columns names coming from algorithm

Comment: Forget everything you know about your problem - put yourself in the shoes of somebody who doesn't know you, doesn't know your problem, and just reads what you posted. Do you think this is enough information? "where column names coming from algorithm"? Where do we start?

Comment: I want to execute the query ->>>String q1="CREATE TABLE table1 AS (SELECT PID,:qs1,:qs2 FROM patient)";    ............Where qs1 and qs2 are two variables coming from another class which are column names of the old table ............But i am getting binding variables are not allowed error,,,,,,,,,,,,How can i resolve this problem..Please help me

Comment: Do you *really* need a program that will keep creating tables with *pseudo-random* columns? Maybe there's another way to solve your real-life problem. Anyway, have you tried `String query = "CREATE TABLE t1 AS (SELECT " + qs1 + " FROM patient)"`?

Comment: It worked.....Thank you... MiguelKVidal